# Adding cisco switch to an existing stack with slightly different naming convention

Tags: stacking

I'm new to networking and I'm gearing up to add a switch to an existing stack at my job. The existing stacks are showing the following when I issue the show version command:

Switch Ports Model              SW Version        SW Image              Mode

---

- 1 56    WS-C3850-48P       03.07.05E         cat3k_caa-universalk9 INSTALL

  2 56    WS-C3850-48P       03.07.05E         cat3k_caa-universalk9 INSTALL

  3 56    WS-C3850-48P       03.07.05E         cat3k_caa-universalk9 INSTALL

The switch I'm preparing to add to this stack is currently showing the following (I already renumbered and set the priority on it):

Switch Ports Model              SW Version        SW Image              Mode

---

- 4 56    WS-C3850-48U       03.07.05E         cat3k_caa-universalk9 INSTALL

Will it cause any problems when I add the 48U model since the existing models are 48P? I believe the U is for UPOE and the P is PoE.

also...

I noticed the following on a label attached to each switch in the existing stack of 3 that reads WS-C3850-48F-S and the label on the one switch I plan to add reads WS-C3850-48U-L. I am very confused by the different information displayed when using the show version command versus what appears on the label attached to the switches by the manufacturer. Any help you can give is greatly appreciated.

Comment: *F* vs *U* differ in PoE: *F* is IEEE PoE+ (25.5 W) and *U* is proprietary Cisco UPoE (60 W). *S* stands for *IP Service* image/license, *L* is *LAN Base*.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer my question. Your response has been very helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should not be a problem, as long as IOS Version, License are same.

https://community.cisco.com/t5/switching/can-i-mix-poe-and-non-poe-3750-s-in-a-stack/td-p/3011926

Comment: Well, the license *isn't* the same, see my comment.

Comment: It will look for what is installed on the device, not the one on the label (in case they are different).

Type 'show license right-to-use' on existing and new switch. If the output is same, then you are good to go.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer my question. Your response has been very helpful!

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept the answer, so the question can be marked as been answered.